# setting android button invisible but still having an onClick Listener attached

Tags: android, android-button, invisible

So currently I'm putting an Easter egg inside my app and I want the `Button` to be invisible, but when clicked(Rick roll). So far I can make it work when I say:

```
Button.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
Button.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

and then my `onClickListener`. The only problem with this is that I have to have text on the `Button` for it to be clickable. When I take the text out and make it completely invisible then the `onClickListener` is never called for some reason?

Here is my `OnClickListener`

```
wonderWhatThisDoes.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(About.this, R.raw.surprise);
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Congrats on finding our easter egg! Enjoy... :]";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Post the code how do you implement the `OnClickListener()`?

Comment: onClickListener implementation doesn't matter if it never gets called.

Comment: If the width and height of your Button is set to wrap_content, then perhaps the button is getting too small to touch when there is no content. Having the text will make it bigger as the width and height will grow.

Comment: I agree with @Steve Prentice's answer. Since you have -->" "<-- this big text on the button and use wrap_content, the user will not have content where to click

Comment: Nice! great answers guys. That was definitely it. wrap_content was making it too small for me to click. many people will now get rick roll'd thanks to you :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your layout, make your button have a specific width, like `android:layout_width="40dp"`.

If your width is set to `wrap_content` with a transparent background and no text, Android will measure that view as having a width of 0dp. You'll never be able to click on that.

Comment: The same applies to height.  I am using a RelativeLayout.  The solution that worked for me was to just set the width and height to outlandishly large values, to make sure the area isn't too small, but using `layout_align*` functions in conjunction.

Answer (score 6):

Simple answer is set alpha to 0 like this.

```
 <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:alpha="0"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="getAllImages"
                android:visibility="visible" />
```

It will be invisible and onclick will work.

Comment: easiest and elegant solution

Answer (score 5):

try making the text in the button " "...

```
myButton.setText("    ");
```

Comment: doesn't work. I've already tried specifying the text in xml to "  " and the onClickListener still doesn't get called :'(

Comment: well, setting the text to "" is equivelent to setting it to (null). try setting it to " " just for kicks.

Answer (score 4):

You can create any view, such as LinearLayout, as clickable.  Make a LinearLayout with the same dimensions as the button and set it's onClick listener to whatever handles the event.  Since it inherently isn't visible, it should hold the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your button's width and height are not set to `wrap_content` because that would cause the button to be extremely small if the text is " ". If that doesn't work, you could also try replacing onClick() with onTouch():

```
button1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a button and override your Activity's dispatchTouchEvent and handle it that way.

Comment: Or use a transparent background for the button with a fixed size.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `OnClickListener` to any `View`, so try creating an `ImageView` with a transparent image and attach your listener to that.

Comment: He won't even need a transparent image if he uses any generic view.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
     Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
     b.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

     b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cb.setChecked(true);
```

to this code button is invisible but it worked ;))

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable the button (It will not be clickable).

In java code:

```
btn.setClickable(false);
```

In .xml layout:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

Answer (score -1):

This works properly for me:

- `btn.setClickable(false)` on `GONE` visibility.
- `btn.setClickable(true)` on `VISIBLE` visibility.