# onClick function does not execute when button invisible and visible feature is on - android

Tags: android, button, onclick, touch

In my android application when I touch the fragment, the button becomes invisible and when I release my finger button becomes visible. This is the behavior I wanted.

**But somehow my `onclick` function on the button does not execute because of this.**

So, I tried removing the invisible and visible feature. Then `onClick` function executes when I touch the button.

**So why `onClick` function does not execute when invisible and visible feature is on?**

***Buttons Layout:***

```
<Button
   android:layout_width="200dp"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   android:text="Open Camera"
   android:id="@+id/camera_btn"
   android:background="#ffffff"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Here I have set a fixed width and height according to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851644/setting-android-button-invisible-but-still-having-an-onclick-listener-attached).

***Code that makes the button invisible and visible on touch and release:***

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                MapsActivity.mMapIsTouched = true;
                hideElementsOnMapTouch();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                MapsActivity.mMapIsTouched = false;
                showElementsOnMapTouchRelease();
                getCenterLocation();
                break;
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}

public void hideElementsOnMapTouch()
{
        centerLocation_txt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        camera_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

public void showElementsOnMapTouchRelease()
{
        centerLocation_txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        camera_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

***Button onClick Listener:***

```
public void onCameraButtonClicked()
    {

        camera_btn.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.d("myApp", "no network");
                        Intent camera_intent = new Intent("com.example.lalinda.googlemap1.Camera");
                        startActivity(camera_intent);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Did you try using the `OnTouchListener` instead of dispatching touch events?

Comment: @milosmns No, Is it because of the `dispatchTouchEvent` function? What is the recommended way, `dispatchTouchEvent` or `OnTouchListener`?

Comment: I'm just guessing, not sure. I always prefer a view listener instead of overriding activity medhods